# Android IAB product only for selected countries?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, subscription, android-billing

I am trying to have IAB subscription in my app targeting people in particular location. Can we create a subscription/sku targeted only for a specific country?

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can. Go to your developer console and from in app purchases , select add new subscription. A complete example can be found in your sdk extra folder if you have installed in app billing in your sdk manager.